# How to make "int" based on number from database? - Java

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, integer

I'm making a game, so far I've made two buttons for the test. The first button makes a win, and the second one loses, all this is added to the database.

[image]

```
int win_int = 0;
int lose_int = 0;
```

The fact is that every time you enter this activity, the number is reset to zero, since I set the number 0 in the variable. I want to understand how to make "integer" take a number not just one, but the number that is in the database.

Here are the codes for the two buttons:

```
Button win = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Poke);
win.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        winsRef = database.getReference();
        winsRef.child("players/").child(playerName).child("/wins").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                dataSnapshot.getRef().setValue(win_int = win_int + 1);
                Toast.makeText(DuelGame.this, "+1 win!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Toast.makeText(DuelGame.this, "Data error!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
});

Button lose = (Button)findViewById(R.id.lose_POKE);
lose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        losesRef = database.getReference();
        losesRef.child("players/").child(playerName).child("/loses").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                dataSnapshot.getRef().setValue(lose_int = lose_int + 1);
                Toast.makeText(DuelGame.this, "+1 Lose!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Toast.makeText(DuelGame.this, "Data error!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

In general, I want that every time I enter the activity, the number is not reset to zero, and Integer takes the number from the database and is based on them, and not on zero in the variable.

Comment: That all sounds like a reasonable use-case. Which specific line in the code you shared doesn't do what you expect it to do though?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen all work, but I made variable int win_int = 0; , that is, its number is naturally Zero, when I enter this activity, then in the database my victories and defeats are reset to zero, since the variable = 0, I want to make Integer Based on the number from the database

Comment: You need to initialize your variable by reading its current value from database. Something like `loseInt = dataSnapshot.getRef().getValue()` I am not sure of the syntax or API.

Comment: @SameerNaik I don't quite understand what you mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to increment a value in the database, you can use the [atomic increment operation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#atomic_server-side_increments):

```
Map updates = new HashMap();
updates.put("wins", ServerValue.increment(1));

database.getReference().child("players/").child(playerName).updateChildren(updates);
```